# Land temperature anomaly data from earth observations in R

Tags: raster, r, geotiff-tiff, nasa

I am trying to work with the NASA's land temperature anomaly dataset at https://neo.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/view.php?datasetId=MOD_LSTAD_M&date=2013-01-01

When I am using the extract function on the raster file <downloaded at 0.1 degrees>, I am getting abnormally high range >100 - 160. The earth observation is showing that these values range from -12 to 12 for this particular month (January, 2013).

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I also downloaded the GeoTiff (floating point), but still getting the same values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me. If I select GeoTIFF (Floating Point) and download I get a file called `MOD_LSTAD_M_2013-01-01_gs_360x180.FLOAT.TIFF`. I can load that into R:

```
> r = raster("./MOD_LSTAD_M_2013-01-01_gs_360x180.FLOAT.TIFF")
> range(r[])
[1]   -12 99999
```

The 99999 value is the ocean or other missing data, so lets set that to `NA`:

```
> r[r[]>99000] = NA
> range(r[])
[1] NA NA
> range(r[],na.rm=TRUE)
[1] -12.00  10.96
```

which is now in the range of anomaly values you expect.

I get the same for the `MOD_LSTAD_M_2013-01-01_gs_720x360.FLOAT.TIFF` higher resolution file - I've not tried the others yet.

```
 plot(r)
```

[image]

You've not said exactly how you are using the `extract` function, so perhaps you are accidentally extracting some of those 99999 values into your extraction, thus messing up your answers. In which case you want to convert 99999 to `NA` as above, and make sure your extraction function ignores `NA` values.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! You have solved two of my problems in two days. Really appreciate the consideration. I tried it with the highest resolution and it worked there too.

Comment: Great to help! If you can click the tick to show this is the answer, I'll get some magic stack overflow points and you'll get something too. Its up there on the left top of the answer...